# How to find smallest value in a binary search tree?

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I have to write a client method that returns a reference to the information in the node with the smallest value in a binary search tree using the codes given.

Here is the [ZIP FILE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/x0nm23dj4kti4p4/GolfAppsFiles.zip?dl=0)

I have to use this signature of method:

> Golfer min(BinarySearchTree tree)

Here's what I have written:

```
   Golfer min(BinarySearchTree<Golfer> tree)
   {
      int treeSize = tree.reset(BinarySearchTree.INORDER);
      int numNodes = 0;
      for(int count = 1; count <= treeSize; count++)
      {
         if((tree.getNext(BinarySearchTree.INORDER).compareTo(maxValue)) <= 0)
            numNodes = numNodes + 1;
      }
      return numNodes;     
   }
```

Comment: the smallest value or the smallest key?

Comment: You have a function labeled min, but you're returning something called numNodes.....there's a hint.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou I double checked and it states smallest value in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you are looking for the Golfer with the minimum score

Method 1: O(lg(n)) time because it runs down the left side of the tree

```
public Golfer min(BinarySearchTree<Golfer> tree) {
    BSTNode<Golfer> node = tree.root;
    if (node == null) {
        return null;
    }
    while (node.getLeft() != null) {
        node = node.getLeft();
    }
    return node.getInfo();
}
```

Method 2: O(n) time because it runs through all the elements in the tree to create an in order traversal

```
public Golfer min2(BinarySearchTree<Golfer> tree) {
    int treeSize = tree.reset(BinarySearchTree.INORDER);
    if (treeSize <= 0) {
        return null;
    }
    return tree.getNext(BinarySearchTree.INORDER);
}
```

Here is some code to test the code above

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BinarySearchTree<Golfer> bst = new BinarySearchTree<Golfer>();
    bst.add(new Golfer("A", 10));
    bst.add(new Golfer("B", 12));
    bst.add(new Golfer("C", 8));
    bst.add(new Golfer("D", 9));
    bst.add(new Golfer("E", 3));

    Golfer min = new Test().min(bst);
    //Golfer min = new Test().min2(bst);
    if (min != null) {
        System.out.println("min name: " + min.name + ", min score: " + min.score);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Empty tree");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
min name: E, min score: 3
```